# Add image on another image in android

Tags: android, image, canvas, imageview, mapping

In my application, I want to add an image on another image and also when user zoom on image at that time it should also move, Just like google map.
Please have a look at below image and i want to set flag dynamically

[image]

Please advice better way to complete this task.

Comment: you can use canvas

Comment: @jagapathi how can i add canvas on image

Answer (score 0):

Solution (XML):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/t" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tt" />
</layer-list>
```

Solution (dynamic):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="maxdorid.ir.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</RelativeLayout>


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Resources r = getResources();
        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
        layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_alarm_off_black_24dp);
        layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_apps_black_24dp);
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
        ImageView imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
    }
}
```

If you use more than one image:

```
private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2,int x,int y) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, x,y, null);
    return bmOverlay;
}
```

Comment: Which method xml or dynamic?

Comment: Edit my answer. Check again.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative layout as background and place the images as the component of relative layout, use the relative layout params to adjust the images locations on the screen.you can apply zoom on the relative layout itself